# $f^{-1}(U)=S$ always open in $S$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I follow the proof for (a) but am unsure on a thing. But why is $f^{-1}(U)=S$ always open in $S$? I mean that would mean $S$ is open but why is $S$ open?

credit to Hawaii.edu
[image: Math 431 - Real Analysis I Hawaii.edu]

Comment: $f^{-1}(U)$ is a set, and every set is open in a discrete space.

Answer (score 2):

In every metric (or more generaly, topological) space $X$, two sets are always open for trivial reasons: the empty set $\emptyset$ and the space $X$ itself.

- For every $x\in \emptyset$, *vacuously* the open ball of radius $42$ is also $\subseteq \emptyset$
- For $x\in X$, the open ball $B_{42}(x)=\{\,y\in X\mid d(x,y)<42\,\}$ is *trivially* also $\subseteq X$.

Comment: I see. So if the open ball is $\subseteq$ to the set then we conclude the set is open

Comment: @mathstudent23 Yes, that's the definition of an open set. If $X$ is a metric space and $E \subseteq X$, then $E$ is open if and only if for every point $p$ of $E$, there exists some ball $B_r(p)$ of non-zero radius which is $\subseteq E$.